# Custom grid view with different columns

Tags: java, android

I am developing a custom grid view with different columns.

**ViewPossibilities Mockup**

[image: View Possibilities Mockup]

Here is the full demo.  You can directly use it, with Internet uses permission.

This works perfectly but I want to optimize it.

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.rtrt;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int width = 0;
    int position = 0;
    ArrayList<String> arr_string = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout girdviewcustom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.girdviewcustom);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
                .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
        arr_string
        .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");

        int size = arr_string.size();

        if (size == 1)
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewone());
        else if (size == 2)
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
        else if (size == 3)
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        else if (size == 4) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
        } else if (size == 5) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        } else if (size == 6) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        } else if (size == 7) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        } else if (size == 8) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        } else if (size == 9) {
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
            girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
        } else {
            int mod = (size % 3);
            if (mod != 0)
                mod = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < ((size / 3) + (mod)); i++) {

                girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public View getViewone() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
        ImageView a11 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a11);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                .resize(width, width).into(a11);
        position++;
        return myView;

    }

    public View getViewTwo() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, null);
        ImageView a21 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a21);
        ImageView a22 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a22);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                .resize(width / 2, width / 2).into(a21);
        position++;
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                .resize(width / 2, width / 2).into(a22);
        position++;
        return myView;

    }

    public View getViewThree() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_three, null);
        ImageView a31 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a31);
        ImageView a32 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a32);
        ImageView a33 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.a33);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                .resize(width / 3, width / 3).into(a31);
        position++;
        if (arr_string.size() > position) {
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                    .resize(width / 3, width / 3).into(a32);
            position++;
            if (arr_string.size() > position) {
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arr_string.get(position))
                        .resize(width / 3, width / 3).into(a33);
                position++;
            }
        }
        return myView;

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/girdviewcustom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_one.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_two.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_three.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a31"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a32"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: While it is nice to see you incorporating my review in your code, I would like you to refrain from editing parts of the code, that I talked about. We call this answer invalidation. More information in [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). In accordance to the rules defined there I rolled back your edit. I bet you will get another answer on this question in the next 30 hours. Have patience ;)

Comment: "You can directly use it, with Internet uses permission". We don't have the `Picasso` class, whatever that is. And why is Internet permissions that important for this code?

Comment: @Dedaniyahirenkumar: [We are allowed to use it anyway](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: what Does menu fold contain?...It has main, what does main contain...can have snippet of main in menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Variables

```
int width = 0;
int position = 0;
ArrayList<String> arr_string = new ArrayList<String>();
```

These variables should be `private final` and the `ArrayList` should be *declared* as `List` to allow easier switch to another List implementation.

```
private final int width = 0;
private final int position = 0;
private final List<String> arr_string = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

## XML

Considering the pattern of your XML files, you might want to create the layouts *dynamically*, with code, instead of using XML files.

I don't really see why you're wrapping all your inner LinearLayouts inside an outer LinearLayout in your `layout_one-three.xml` I *think* that you can remove

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

in those files without any difference in behavior.

I am not a big fan of your naming scheme for your android IDs, such as `android:id="@+id/a22"`.

---

## If-else-if-else-if-else...

Your `if-else-if-else-if-else-if` can be *switched* to a `switch (size)` statement which would make it a bit more clear what's going on there. Also, it is very easy to miss that the first if's don't use braces, which leads us to the common suggestion *always use braces*. If you switch to a `switch`, you won't use braces but `break;` instead.

I believe this part of your code can be simplified a lot by using some mathematics instead of hardcoding the system. I haven't found out the exact solution yet though. But I do believe that the `if (size == 9) {` specific case is useless as that is exactly what will happen with your last else-block, which btw can be a bit simplified:

```
int mod = (size % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
for (int i = 0; i < size / 3 + mod; i++) {
    girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
}
```

#### Edit:

Instead of for your whole sequence of if-else:

```
public static int[] rows(int i) {
    final int firstRow;
    if (i == 1) {
        firstRow = 1;
    }
    else firstRow = i % 3 == 0 ? 3 : 2;
    final int secondRow;
    if (i <= 3) {
        secondRow = 0;
    }
    else secondRow = i % 3 == 1 ? 2 : 3;
    final int thirdRow = i >= 7 ? 3 : 0;

    return new int[]{ firstRow, secondRow, thirdRow };
}

private void makeRow(int columns) {
    switch (columns) {
       case 1:
           girdviewcustom.addView(getViewOne());
           break;
       case 2:
           girdviewcustom.addView(getViewTwo());
           break;
       case 3:
           girdviewcustom.addView(getViewThree());
           break;
       default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid count: " + columns);
    }
}
```

And then the code in your activity:

```
int size = arr_string.size();
int[] rows = rows(size);
for (int i : rows) {
    if (i > 0) {
        makeRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and I put mockup screen for understanding

Comment: @Dedaniyahirenkumar Thanks for the mockup screen, that helped a lot. See the edit I made.

Comment: Thanks for your optimized code. Its really helpful for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>             .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
>     arr_string
>     .add("http://www.bluesodapromo.com/static/DesignCenter/Image/dc_images/clipart/nature/nature_1.png");
> ```

Just three little things that strike me in this code:

#### Repetition of doom / copy pasta

Whenever you copy/paste, in your head there should be a signal lamp flashing. **Don't copy paste.** There are some moments when you can ignore it, but all else equal you should extract a method / change to a loop.

A code that does the exact same thing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    arr_string.add("http://" /* */);
}
```

#### Indentation

The last `.add()` is placed oddly.
all others are subdented, but that one is on the outer level...

#### Naming

I don't know about android, but usually the java-convention for fields, variables and methods is `camelCase`, your `arr_string` uses `snake_case`. And the name could definitely be better in itself.

Comment: That I know, It just for demo purpose. I just want help in arranging view with optimized code. All other things which you mention that I follow. Thanks for that. If you can help me to optimize code then please tell me.

Comment: Please See my edit